# the css transform:translate to align a div in the center ist not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, compatibility, css-transforms

im use the following css code for a div container

```
/*media all*/
.rent-a-home-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate( 50%, 50% );
    text-align: center;
}
```

The Css works for all browsers but not for Internet explorer. The div with the font is not aligned to the center.

Here you can see: https://www.immvestwolf.de/rent-a-home-2

Thanks!

Comment: It would have to be `translate(-50%, -50%)` for centering both axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look with my browser inspector tool and saw the issue right away. Apparently internet explorer has a problem with the space you leave before you close the ")". The correct syntax would therefore be:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

instead of

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50% );
```

Comment: there is also a .JS error from an external script... is it possible to fix it without the help from air bnb?

Comment: @tom84 Just a shout here, not sure if this would work at all, but after loading the script you could try to overwrite the script with your own, but this would probably cause alot of bugs so I wouldn't try.

Comment: If you have problems with cdn scripts throwing errors you can just download the script (opening the url of the script in a browser tab) and save it locally and then include it in the project.

Comment: ah ok! thanks! this is a possibility! Is this a huge java script error i have to fix? Or it is only a little thing?

Comment: You'll find out yourself if the script works its fine otherwhise you should fix it

Answer (score 0):

The correct code would be:

```
.rent-a-home-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
    text-align: center;
}
```

Because the code without MINUS 50% would translate the `rent-a-home-center` div farther towards the bottom right, instead of translating it to the top left so that the div's middle point is actually in the middle of the page.

Link to translate() css documentation (has illustration): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

Comment: although this is correct, he just has a typo in his question. he has "transform: translate(-50%. -50% ) in his css

Comment: thanks for your answer... but also with minus it is not working in Internet explorer